# Python: can unittest display expected and actual values?

Tags: python, unit-testing

If I have an assert in a unittest.TestCase as shown below:

```
self.assertTrue( person.age == 42, "age incorrect")
```

When it fails, it gives the "age incorrect" message. What I would also like to see is the  expected and actual values. What's the best way to go about doing this? Is it something unittest can do?

**EDIT**
I would like to see something like:

"age incorrect: expected value 42 actual value 39"

Comment: `self.assert` is a syntax error. You mean `self.assert_`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've meant to write assertTrue...updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a workaround to this problem, like this:

```
self.assertEqual(person.age, 42, 'age incorrect: expected value {0} actual value {1}'.format(42, person.age))
```

But i think not providing the "msg" parameter is the best option, since it generates the text:

```
first != equal
```

Most(*) tools for running tests also shows directly which line failed, thus you should be able to understand which test failed and why without using an extra message.

(*) read "all".

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realised that not adding the message gave actual and expected.

Comment: This violates the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: @Rockallite Did you even read the *whole* answer? I believe you missed all the lines except for the first two.

Comment: @Bakuriu Showing directly which line failed doesn't mean you are able to know the expected and actual values, especially when the test **fails**. And showing the msg parameter along with asserting values isn't that hard. You don't need to write the values twice. Just set the `longMessage` property of the `TestCase` instance to `True`.

Comment: @Rockallite   WTF? Who is talking about "line failed"? Read the answer again: `not providing the "msg" parameter is the best option, since it generates the text:  first != equal`, i.e. doing `assertEqual(person.age, 42)` will result in an error saying (say) `35 != 42` which is what the OP wanted (except that it is more concise).

Comment: @Bakuriu The question is asking how to show the error message *and* the asserting values at the same time. (See the last sentence of the question.) Also I think showing the error message is an intuitive way to let user understand what is going on. It's just as important as the asserting values. Besides, there's a very easy way to implement this, as I mentioned.

Comment: @Rockallite Given that the Op accepted my answer I believe you are mistaking the interpretation of the question. The OP was good with **anything** that displayed the values that didn't match, and everything more is a plus. If you think there are better ways to do this: fine, write your own answer or just upvote the existing one or use a bounty to reward it, I don't see the reason to spend a downvote to a valid answer when there's plenty of stuff on the site that is utterly wrong and should deserve it quite more.

Comment: A valid answer does not make a good answer, and it is certainly at @Rockallite's discretion how poor it needs to be to downvote. I wouldn't downvote it personally, but it does make me frown.

Answer (score 30):

you can set the `longMessage` attribute to `True`

```
expected_age = 42
actual_age = person.age # 39
self.longMessage = True
self.assertEqual(expected_age, actual_age, 'age incorrect')
```

you would get something like:

```
AssertionError: 42 != 39 : age incorrect
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage

Comment: that's _exactly_ what I felt should exist.  Excellent answer!

Answer (score 5):

see: [assertEqual](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual)

```
self.assertEqual(person.age, 42, 'age incorrect')
```

or with the default message (to answer the comment):

```
self.assertEqual(person.age, 42)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It still printed out "age incorrect", but not the actual value i.e., the value of person.age.